# Explanation about the Scanner in line

Tags: java

So I just started learning Java and I couldn't understand what does the line - Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
mean, can some one explain to me? thanks!

Here is a code I worked on recently..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class C1P30 {
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        int num1, num2;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter firtst number: ");
        num1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Second number: ");
        num2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The numbers are:");
        System.out.println(num1);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(num2);
    }


}
```

Comment: It creates a new [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) instance on the [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html) [`System.in`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#in) (which usually is the console input)

Comment: I think everything is explained [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Comment: Thanks guys, appreciate it

Comment: Scanner nextLine() method in Java with Examples  -https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-nextline-method-in-java-with-examples/

Answer (score 1):

**This line instantiates an object of type `Scanner` which is capable of reading keyboard input.**

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
```

---

Breaking it down...

`System.in` is an `InputStream` which is typically connected to keyboard input.

`Scanner` is a simple text scanner that can read an `InputStream`.

`new` is a keyword in Java that creates an object based on a class (instantiation) and returns a reference to it. It also allocates memory for the object on the heap.

`Scanner in` initializes a `Scanner` variable and names it `in`.